# Using try, except and else in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on these try/except/else statements but I have a problem.

I'd like to put a code like this :

```
try:
   ...
except:
   ...
else:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

But I know it's impossible to put 2 "else" consecutively.
I tried an "elif" but I read that it doesn't work inside an "except". And it did not work.
So how could I do to make 2 or more than 2 "else" statements ?

Thank you !
Julien

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? At the moment - I'm not sure this is a question...

Comment: Are you trying to catch two different kinds of exception? e.g. if the block in the `try` clause could throw either `ValueError` or `TypeError`, and you want to have different behaviour depending on which one...

Answer (score 6):

You will never need two else block. If you need to further distinguish within the `else`, do:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...  
else:
    if condition:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply put everything in one else branch?

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
   ...
except:
   ...
else:
    if:
    ...
    elif:
    ...
    else:
    ...
```

If your action is dependent on the exception you get:

```
try:
   ...
except FirsException:
   #handle_first_one()

except SecondException:
   #handle_second_one()
```